# In GraphQL, can you change the structure of the output in an alias?

Tags: graphql

Let's say I've got a GraphQL query that looks like this:

```
query {
  Todo {
    label
    is_completed
    id
  }
}
```

But the client that consumes the data from this query needs a data structure that's a bit different- e.g. a TypeScript interface like:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string  // "title" is just a different name for "label"
  data: {
    is_completed: boolean
    id: number
  }
}
```

It's easy enough to just use an alias to return `label` as `title`. But is there any way to make it return both `is_completed` and `id` under an alias called `data`?

Comment: what client? apollo? data fetched by apollo can be easily converted to [react component] desired format f.e. using some wrapper/HOC

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444837/change-the-structure-of-a-graphql-response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Either change the schema to reflect the client's needs or transform the response after it is fetched on the client side.